# Summernote onkeyup function replace special characters

Tags: html, node.js, summernote

I need to replace some special characters when typed or pasted to something else in summernote textarea.

This don't work at onkeypup function:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#content').summernote({
              placeholder: 'Treść...',
              tabsize: 2,
              //height: 300,
              lang: 'pl-PL', // default: 'en-US'
              toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture']],
                ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']]
              ],
              callbacks: {
                onKeyup: function(e) {
                                setTimeout(function(){
  //    $("#result").html($('.description').val());
  var y = $('#content').summernote("code");
  console.log("y: ",y);
        var x = y.replaceAll(/[^]/g, '');
            console.log("x: ",x);
  },200);
                
},
    onPaste: function (e) {
        var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
        e.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
    }
}
            });
        });
          
          </script>
```

html:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I was trying this way too:

```
onKeyup: function(e) {
                  $('#summernote').code().replace(/(<([^]+)>);/ig, '');
},
```

How it is possible to change any `^` to nothing, null, empty?

edit:
maybe fiddle will help https://jsfiddle.net/v4qdph6f/

edit2: fiddle updated, only replace don't work

Comment: the additional `.this.` in `$('#summernote').this.value =` looks suspicious

Comment: I would expect `this.value = this.value.replaceAll("^", "");`

Comment: it works in simple input without summernote :)

Comment: Also give summernote a millisecond https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533950/summernote-onkeyup-event-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: Don't work with `setTimeout`, `.replaceAll("^", "");`

Comment: Shoudl be `$('#content').` instead `$('#summernote').` but it doesn't work

Comment: and `const tgt = e.target; console.log(tgt.value); tgt.value = tgt.value.replaceAll("^", ""); console.log(tgt.value);` I added the console.log to see if it did anything

Comment: @mplungjan I have made some changes in jsfiddle from Your sugesstion, it replace special char but don't refresh summernote textarea: https://jsfiddle.net/v4qdph6f/